# How can I create or setup multiple accounts for Rinkeby in a Truffle environment?

Tags: truffle, wallets, accounts, testing, rinkeby

I use `ethereumjs-wallet` along with `truffle-wallet-provider` to connect my Rinkeby account to Truffle:

```
var rinkebyPrivateKey = new Buffer(process.env["RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY"], "hex")
var rinkebyWallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(rinkebyPrivateKey);
var rinkebyProvider = new WalletProvider(rinkebyWallet, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/");
```

Since `WalletProvider` is used to create one single Rinkeby provider, I don't see how I could pass in more accounts' credentials. Can anyone point me to some resources for setting up these accounts so I can use them in my Truffle tests and/or console?